# D3 Transitions - Making changes throughout transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have an SVG and a chart that renders inside the SVG based on the width and height. I would like to set up a page where there are multiple SVGs each containing a chart and the SVG that is clicked then expands a bit. I can do this without a transition, but I'd like to make it visually appealing. It would be great if I could do something like:

```
svg.transition().duration(whatever).attr("width",whatever);
```

but I want to be continuously running the chart resize function as the transition is happening. Of course I could kick off a transition on the svg and then a separate transition on the chart elements, but my understanding is that isn't guaranteed to progress at the same pace and that the timing on transitions is not guaranteed to be exact. The easiest way I can think to do this would be to set some kind of listener on the width attribute of the SVG, but some stack overflow searches indicate that's not possible. They all suggest a setter function that calls the listener then resets the value but that doesn't work here because the transition is taking care of all that.

Also once I'm done I'll be doing more than just adjusting the width I don't need help with that, I'd just like to know if there's a way to run the chart resize function as the transition progresses here somehow such that as the svg transitions the chart will continue to be the right size.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In `d3` version 4, [transitions now take an optional parameter](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#transitions-d3-transition) of another transition that can be used to synchronize transitions across elements. From that documentation here's an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
  
    var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width',600)
      .attr('height',500);
      
    svg.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'apple')
      .attr('r', 200)
      .attr('cx', 200)
      .attr('cy', 250)
      .style('fill', 'black');
      
    svg.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'orange')
      .attr('r', 200)
      .attr('cx', 400)
      .attr('cy', 250)
      .style('fill', 'black');
  
    var t = d3.transition()
      .duration(7000)
      .ease(d3.easeLinear);

    d3.selectAll(".apple").transition(t)
      .style("fill", "red");

    d3.selectAll(".orange").transition(t)
      .style("fill", "orange");
  </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

An alternative approach is to create a custom tween function that'll perform both animations in a single transition:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
  
    var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width',600)
      .attr('height',500);
      
    svg.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'apple')
      .attr('r', 200)
      .attr('cx', 200)
      .attr('cy', 250)
      .style('fill', 'black');
      
    svg.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'orange')
      .attr('r', 200)
      .attr('cx', 400)
      .attr('cy', 250)
      .style('fill', 'black');
  
    var t = d3.transition()
      .duration(7000)
      .ease(d3.easeLinear)
      .tween("attr.fill", function() {
        var apple = d3.selectAll(".apple"),
            orange = d3.selectAll(".orange"),
            i1 = d3.interpolateRgb(apple.style("fill"), "red"),
            i2 = d3.interpolateRgb(orange.style("fill"), "orange");
        return function(t) {
          apple.style("fill", i1(t));
          orange.style("fill", i2(t));
        };
      });
  </script>
  </body>

</html>
```